# The choice of [no article/a] hotel was perfect

Tags: articles

Intuitively, it seems that articles are not necessary here.

> The choice of hotel was perfect.

Nonetheless, I can't find a logical way to explain why omitting articles for a countable noun is grammatical. Is it?

Comment: they are both grammatical.  They mean different things.

Comment: Case 1. The choice of a hotel must not be made randomly. 

Case 2. We are really glad to have stayed at Hotel X. We think that our choice of hotel was just right! 

Do I understand the difference correctly?

Comment: "The choice of hotel was perfect." = "I'm so glad you picked this hotel out of all the other options." VS "The choice of a hotel was perfect." = "I'm so glad you decided to stay at a hotel as opposed to an Airbnb or an apartment or some other form of temporary residence."

Comment: @TommyTran - Yes. Exactly right.

Comment: @TommyTran, thank you. Why do we treat the countable noun in this case as if it were uncountable and omit articles? Even though I can "feel" the difference in meaning, I also feel that I need to clarify this use case grammatically.

Comment: Timur: I found [a fully explicit formulation of what is, for native speakers, a trivial rule of the language — the choice of definite article, indefinite article, or no definite article.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22choice+of+definite+article%2C+indefinite+article%2C+or+no+definite+article%22) Where the writer helpfully points out that he *could* alternatively have ended that sentence with *the choice of **the** definite article, **the** indefinite article, or no definite article*. You might find something helpful in what else the guy says, but I wouldn't count on it. Idiomacy.

Comment: (By "idiomacy", I mean that if you can "feel" the difference, you probably know as much as any native speaker does about why we all make the distinction so nicely outlined by @Tommy above! :)

Comment: @TimurSharapov Why not post that as an answer?